# Is it possible to identify a WordPress Theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have this website https://londonrealacademy.com/ and I need a wordpress theme closest to this site. Is it possible to search?

Comment: I don't understand why this question has 4 downvotes. Seems a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check theme by source code of site.
view source code and check link of any theme file like

```
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://londonrealacademy.com/wp-content/themes/kleo/assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://londonrealacademy.com/wp-content/themes/kleo/assets/css/fontello-ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Here used theme is 'Kleo'

Comment: This answer isn't 100% guaranteed to work. If the user were to change the name of the folder on their server or something this method no longer works. Most of the time it will probably work but there are defiantly cases where it might not be correct.

Answer (score 1):

A second method allows you to see both Theme and Plugins. Open the site in Chrome and either right-click and select "Inspect" or open "Developer Tools" from Chrome's "More Tools" menu. Then select the "Sources" tab and open the "wp_content" folder.

In the image below (from a different site where the theme has its own plugins), you can see that the theme (for this test site) is "Finanza". The theme's plugins include di-menu, fancybox, etc. The other plugins are Azurecurve toggle showhide, cc child pages, etc.

[image]